# Temperature of spin-glass transition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, spin-models, glass

In the literature on spin glasses I see a lot of theoretical phase diagrams and experimental plots with a definite spin-glass transition temperature $T_\mathrm{G}$. For example, in this figure from [J.A. Mydosh, Rep. Prog. Phys. 78, 052501 (2015)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/78/5/052501) we determine $T_\mathrm{G}$ for each compound from the cusps in magnetic susceptibility:
[image]

However in other glass literature it is stated that the glass transition temperature depends significantly on a cooling rate, and it is one of the important features of the nonequilibrium glass physics. For example, here in [Physics Today](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/PT.3.3052) it is shown by the curves 1, 2, and 3:

[image]

**So how to reconcile these two facts? Does the spin-glass transition temperature depend on the cooling rate and how it is defined?**